# I'm overhauling my blog and … is HTML5 OK?

Tags: html, blogs, css, doctype

I'm overhauling my blog (http://gilesvangruisen.com/) and I'm going to be pushing new technologies as much as possible.

I'm a web designer/developer and the browser percentage is as follows: 
42% Firefox
39% Safari
7% Chrome
7% IE

Is it OK to use the HTML5 doctype for my "rethunk" site?

I thank you.
-Giles :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can safely use the HTML5 doctype `<!doctype html>` and it will just render as HTML strict on [most browsers](http://hsivonen.iki.fi/doctype/), including IE6. Only caveat is that the new [HTML5 elements](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/previewofhtml5) (i.e. `header`, `footer`, [`input type="number"`](http://diveintohtml5.info/detect.html#input-types), etc) isn't directly supported by all browsers, including the current versions.

Comment: There is a JavaScript out there to make IE accept the new elements … might work for all browsers.

Comment: Just to reiterate the point, unless you want a specific other version of HTML, you can always use the HTML5 *doctype*. Using some/all features of the language is another thing, but the doctype itself is always fine. (They checked, extensively.)

Comment: @Nerdling: That's called Modernizr. That's also mentioned in the diveintohtml5 link which I placed behind `input type="number"` in my answer. @Paul: That's correct. Just use `<!doctype html>`. Clean and concise and renders strict even in IE6. Can't be done more easy.

Answer (score 1):

You should feel comfortable using HTML5.  To detect which browsers support some of the next generation browser technologies, you should use a tool like [modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/).

Answer (score 1):

This site is really useful for comparing browser support for features: http://caniuse.com/

Also, you can click "Import stats", which lets you link your Google Analytics profile to the page so it tailors the responses to your site's browser access numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I would give serious thought to using the HTML5 Boilerplate as a starting point. It's HTML5 (obviously) but has been tested for compatibility with a variety of different browsers to make sure it still displays correctly everywhere. It also has jQuery, Modernizr, and normalizr wired in so you've got a good foundation on which to build.

I've never used it for a mostly static site, but it has proven a good starting point for our various apps.